# Is it possible to conditionally set only some values in a MySQL update statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where a user may or may not provide various bits of data that need to go into a row containing that user's info.  The issue is that they need to make multiple entries into the row, over time, and I don't want to null out any pre-existing values, if those had been set in the past.

My desire is to do something that looks (in pseudo code) like this:

var a,b,c;// these are the values that the user provides any of which may be null at any time

```
update user if a != null set name = a,  if b != null set phone = b, if c != null set email c
```

I've been trying to fashion an IF to work in this manner but I get syntax errors with the various ways I've tried. Hoping someone can shed light on the right way to do this (if it's possible).

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to "default" each column to its original value with [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

```
UPDATE user
SET name = COALESCE(a, name),
    phone = COALESCE(b, phone),
    email = COALESCE(c, email)
WHERE ...
```

COALESCE() returns its first non-null argument, so if `a` is null, it'll just return the original value of `name`, so there will be no net change.

MySQL also supports a function ISNULL() which works like COALESCE(), but COALESCE() is standard SQL.  Also, COALESCE() supports more than two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` like:

```
UPDATE user SET name = coalesce(a, name), ...
```

Probably better approach would be to dynamically create your UPDATE statement and include only fields that need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it purely in SQL:

```
UPDATE user
SET name = IF(a IS NULL, name, a),
    phone = IF(b IS NULL, phone, b),
    email = IF(c IS NULL, email, c)
```

Comment: I think I like the coalesce approach better, but +1 anyway for another working alternative.